# Use generator in loss function

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, loss-function

I need to incorporate additional information into a Keras loss function that depends on the current batch. Since Keras losses only take two arguments, I considered adding this information by making the loss function call next() on a generator object. However, the generator is only called once (probably when adding the loss function in model.compile()).
Here is a sample code:

```
data_batches = yield_data_batches()
meta_batches = yield_meta_batches()
....
model.compile(loss=loss_function, ...)
model.fit_generator(generator=data_batches, ....)

def loss_function(x, y):
      meta_x, meta_y = next(meta_batches)
      x *= meta_x  # component-wise matrix multiplication
      y *= meta_y  # component-wise matrix multiplication
      return mse(x, y)
```

Is there a way to make the loss function get a new meta_batch each time it is evaluated on a data_batch? Or is there another way to incorporate this meta information into the loss function?

Clarification:
The meta_x and meta_y are binary matrices that should cancel out certain elements from the prediction as they should not count to the loss.
For example:

`y_true = (a,b,c,0)
y_pred = (d,e,f,g)
y_meta = (1,1,1,0)`

Now, y_pred*y_meta should cancel out g so that it does not count to the loss.

Answer (score 0):

This does not work, since the loss function will be compiled and added to the compute graph. Your loss function may only depend on `y_pred` and `y_true`.

You can either incorporate this information in `y_true`, or weight the resulting loss with sample weights.

Your approach would be equivalent to a combination of both:
Assuming positive weights a and b (you call them meta_x and meta_y):
|ax-by| = a|x-b/a*y|, so you just weight y_pred by b/a and add the sample weight a.

Comment: In my case, the weights are not scalars but matrices. It was supposed to be a component-wise matrix multiplication (I fixed this in the example above). So your approach unfortunately doesn't work.
If I incorporate this information in y_true (i.e. concatenate these two matrices) the neural net has to estimate many more parameters. That is not a feasible solution either.